# How to update multiple rows at once in the database with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have table "BusinessHours" that contains days of the week of the store with opening Hours and Closing hours.

I want to update the values with one query! how to achieve this with sequelize ?

That's the table of the business hours and these are related to one store

Note: that in one query I want to update the whole row for each day.

[image]

Comment: If you want to update different rows with different values then you need to use a cycle because even SQL does not support that in general.

Comment: @Anatoly you mean make a for loop ?

Comment: Exactly, the for loop

Answer (score 2):

In Sequelize, assuming you have a model setup for this, you can update all of the applicable days of the week that have the same hours by using the following:

```
await BusinessHours.update(
   {
     openingTime: <date>,
     closingTime: <date>,
   },
   {
     where: {
       dayOfTheWeek: ['mon', 'tues', ...],
     }
   }
 )
```

If you would like to update any series of days that have different values, those would have to be separate queries.

Keep in mind, you may want to include the `storeId` in your `where` statement depending on your requirements.

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-update](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-update)